# React array state is not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router-component

I want to populate both the array state but projectItems doesn't update in useState and when i put projectItems the component re-renders. so, i am using usecallback but when i put filteredItems and projectItems as dependency array in useCallback and callback in useState, useCallback never runs.

```
const [filteredItems, setfilteredItems] = useState([]);
const [projectItems, setProjectItems] = useState([]);

const { projects } = props;


const callback = useCallback(() => {
        console.log('callback');
        const projectData = projects.map(i => {
            return (
                {
                    key: '1',
                    projectName: i.project_name,
                    size: i.size,
                    location: i.location,
                    status: `Day ${i.Finished_events_days}/${i.total_days_needed}`,
                    score: `${i.score}/10`,
                    view: <a>View Project</a>,
                    download: <a>Download</a>,
                    feedback: <a>Feedback</a>,
                    audit: <a>Audit</a>
                })
        });

        setProjectItems(prevState => [...prevState, ...projectData]);
        console.log(projectItems);
        setfilteredItems([...projectItems]);
    }, [projectItems, filteredItems]);

    useEffect(() => {

    }, [callback]);
```

Comment: `useEffect(() => {  }, [callback]);` - what is it for? And where are you calling the callback?

Comment: I see you are trying to log the updated state from within the same render cycle the state update was enqueued. Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: useEffect(() => {
 callback()
    }, [callback]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

State updates are processed between render cycles, so trying to log or use it will only yield the value from the ***current*** render cycle, not what it *will be* in the ***next*** render cycle.

```
setProjectItems(prevState => [...prevState, ...projectData]);
console.log(projectItems); // <-- current state!
setfilteredItems([...projectItems]); // <-- current state!
```

## Solution

Use an effect hook to "react" to the `projectItems` state update to trigger a `filteredItems` update.

```
...
setProjectItems(prevState => [...prevState, ...projectData]);

...

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(projectItems); // <-- updated state!
  setfilteredItems([...projectItems]); // <-- updated state!
}, [projectItems]);
```

Notes:

- Unless `callback` is *actually* getting passed to a child component I don't think it's necessary to memoize it.
- I don't think `projectItems` should be a dependency since the hook callback function updates it.
- `filteredItems` isn't a dependency because it isn't referenced in the hook callback.

Comment: but, the another problem is useCallback never runs when i pass callback as a dependency in useEffect, why?

Comment: @devesh `useCallback` hook callback will only be invoked when one of the hook's dependencies updates, where the returned memoized callback is used is irrelevant. If the `useCallback` hook has an empty dependency array then it runs only once when the component mounts. From the docs, `useCallback` is useful for passing a stable callback reference to children. From the snippet, granted I may need more context, it doesn't appear `useCallback` is necessary.

Comment: thanks, i read about it. can you give me resource to understand it in more depth.

Comment: @devesh Are you referring to `useCallback` hook? Something other than the react docs for hooks, and specifically that hook?

Comment: i am bot confused why that happend in useeffect. i was asking about resource for hooks apart from official docs.

Comment: @devesh Sorry, are you asking about the `useEffect` in your original snippet or the `useEffect` in my proposed solution? If yours I can't answer as it's an empty code block so I've no idea what it might've been doing, if mine, then it is running the effect callback when the `projectItems` state is updated, which logs the current state and updates the `filteredItems` state. I don't have any react hook resources memorized other than the official docs, though I do know tons of articles/tutorials exist and can be found via google search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `useEffect` method to update the changes to array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setfilteredItems([...projectItems]);
}, [projectItems]);
```